# SQL Server: Ignore rows based on max values

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a table in SQL server with two columns Eff and Week that looks as follows,

```
 Eff           Week
2014-01-11  2014-01-11
2014-01-11  2014-01-18
2014-01-11  2014-01-25
2014-01-25  2014-01-25
2014-01-11  2014-02-01
2014-01-25  2014-02-01
2014-01-11  2014-02-08
2014-01-25  2014-02-08
2014-01-11  2014-02-15
2014-01-25  2014-02-15
2014-01-11  2014-02-22
2014-01-25  2014-02-22
2014-01-11  2014-03-01
2014-01-25  2014-03-01
2014-02-28  2014-03-01
2014-01-11  2014-03-08
2014-01-25  2014-03-08
2014-02-28  2014-03-08
2014-01-11  2014-03-15
2014-01-25  2014-03-15
2014-02-28  2014-03-15
```

I want to create a query from this table that will ignore some of the rows and only put out a table that will contain the week date once but the Eff date might repeat. Basicly it should choose the largets or newest eff date for a week. The new table should look as follows,

```
Eff           Week
2014-01-11  2014-01-11
2014-01-11  2014-01-18
2014-01-25  2014-01-25
2014-01-25  2014-02-01
2014-01-25  2014-02-08
2014-01-25  2014-02-15
2014-01-25  2014-02-22
2014-02-28  2014-03-01
2014-02-28  2014-03-08
2014-02-28  2014-03-15
```

Any pointers?

Comment: So.... what have you tried? We're not just going to give you the query you need. You need to show us that you have put some effort forth.

Comment: Nevermind, it looks as though others have decided it's better to just give you a fish than it is to teach you how to catch fish for yourself.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll - Except that I do make an effort to explain the query so that they have an opportunity to understand and re-apply it another day.  That said, please, here, have my fish, it's been baked with lemon and herbs and tastes wonderful, I hope it makes your tastebuds dance and makes your day feel a little better :)

Comment: @BrianDriscoll I agree with you, however there will always be someone (including myself) who are willing to give away that fish for a small payment when it is this easy to pick up from the ground. For some reason these questions has the best rewards. When we spend hours answering a question, we often do not get any points.

Comment: @MatBailie Your initial answer lacked much other than the query itself, which is when I made my comment. Thank you for updating your answer and taking the time to explain the query.

Answer (score 3):

Do you just mean `The maximum effective date for each week`?

```
SELECT
  week,
  MAX(eff)   AS max_eff
FROM
  yourTable
GROUP BY
  week
ORDER BY
  week
```

The `GROUP BY` take all rows with the same `week` and processes them down to a single row of output.  *(One output row per week, no matter how many input rows there were per week.)*

Then, the `MAX(eff)` allows you to pick the highest value of `eff` within each of those groups.

The `ORDER BY` just sorts the output, it doesn't impact the results in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT MAX(Eff) Eff,Week FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY WEEK;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
SELECT
  MAX(eff) AS MaxEff,
  MIN(eff) AS MinEff,
  week
FROM
  TableDates
GROUP BY 
  week
ORDER BY
  week ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,output is same.

```
select * from
(select *,
ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by datepart(wk,weeks)order by Eff desc)rn from @t
)t4
where rn=1
```